# Ice grid plugin for maven

Tags: maven-2, ice

Does anyone know if there is an [Ice grid](http://www.zeroc.com/icegrid/index.html) plugin for [Maven2](http://maven.apache.org/index.html)?

Currently I will have to call an Ant task from Maven as follows:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [is there a Ice Maven Integration](http://www.zeroc.com/forums/help-center/4050-there-ice-maven-integration.html) thread on the ZeroC forums:

> There is no official plugin for integrate Ice with Maven, you can use ant and slice2java ant task. I not Maven expert but seems that maven could run ant task Maven AntRun Plugin - Usage

And to my knowledge, there is no unofficial support too.

Comment: After more web searching the answer still seems to be no.